# How do i display Breadcrumb name conditionally on response from child.in React with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

I am currently working on a project with React Hooks.

Parent component is a Navigator

1. Child component is a breadcrumb display in this navigator.
2. Child component fetches and displays a view with the data.

How can i use the response data in the 2. child component to set name in the 1. Child component?

My Code (omitted large portions of unnecessary code for this example):

Navigator

```
const { Header, Content } = Layout;
const Navigation = (props: any) => (
    <>
        <Layout>
            <Layout>
                <Header>
                    <Breadcrumbs
                        style={{ flexGrow: 2, paddingLeft: 20 }}
                        name='Name of User'
                    />

                </Header>
                <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px 0', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <div className="content">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={MyPatients} />
                            <Route exact path="/Skjema" component={MySchemas} />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/Pasient"
                                component={() => 
                                    <PatientInfo
                                        patientID={props.history.location.state}
                                    />
                                }
                            />
export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

BreadCrumbs

```
import React from 'react';
import Breadcrumb from 'antd/lib/breadcrumb';
import { HomeOutlined, UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Breadcrumbs = (props: any) => {

    return (

        <>
            <div className="Breadcrumbcontainer" style={props.style}>
                <Breadcrumb>
                    <Breadcrumb.Item href="/">
                        <HomeOutlined />
                        <span style={{ color: 'black' }}>Hjem</span>
                    </Breadcrumb.Item>
                    <Breadcrumb.Item href="Pasient">
                        <UserOutlined />
                        <span style={{ color: 'black' }}>
                            {props.name}
                        </span>
                    </Breadcrumb.Item>
                    <Breadcrumb.Item>
                        <span>Skjema 1 - 17.04.20</span>
                    </Breadcrumb.Item>
                </Breadcrumb>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

The third file contains a fetch  to an api and works fine, the data in question is currently stored as response.name How can i lift this info up to Navigator?

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, there's a parent component that has two child components and you want to trigger a change from one child component in another.

You can maintain the state in the parent component, pass state in child1 and setState function in child2.

```js
// Parent Component
const [name, setName] = useState('');

<>
  <child1 name={name}/>
  <child2 setName={setName}/>
</>
```

Comment: While this seems very easy, I dont have accss to setName in my child component, why is this

Comment: Is it throwing an error? Can you create a sandbox for it?

Comment: Hope this will help [https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-edison-cckqt](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-edison-cckqt)

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the error "setName is not a function" in my child, despite doing exactly as you have done...

Comment: Both references in my parent show that "setName" is the correct function. However, both when i pass it into my child and check where i call it, it says its a var of type any. If it helps, im using Typescript, i should probably have mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I added code sandbox and you can check it out is this what you need. So from parent pass hook as props to a child, and then after the request is made inside of the child component call function from props that will fill the data inside parent component.

[Update state in parent from child](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6njcak?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to the suggestions in this thread. I made my mistake in the passing of the files to the function.

```
const PatientInfo = ({ patientID, setName }: any) => {
    console.log(useFetch<IPatient>( // name of endpoint.... ));
    const { response } = useFetch<IPatient>(
        '// name of endpoint.... + patientID,
        patientID,
    );
```

This ended up fixing my problem. The problem was i initially called the two seperately, like this:

```
const PatientInfo = ({ patientID }: any, { setName } : any) => {
    console.log(useFetch<IPatient>( // name of endpoint.... ));
    const { response } = useFetch<IPatient>(
        '// name of endpoint.... + patientID,
        patientID,
    );
```

So this change worked, although I am not entirely sure as to why.